# How to use gethtmlsource or storeHtmlSource in Selenium Webdriver(Java)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

i want to print html page source in output. In selenium IDE there is a command to  perform this action.

```
storeHtmlSource
```

How to do the same in Selenium Webdriver(Java)?

While exporting the testcase, It shows the following error.

```
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [getHtmlSource |  | ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Selenium WebDriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("your Url here");
String htmlSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

Answer (score -1):

Api doc to get the page source

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/

Comment: Google can help with links, but here https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/